# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length') DataGrid MUI

Tags: javascript, react-redux, material-ui

I'm using react-redux and MUI. And i have a problem while i using DataGrid. When i using DataGrid it will error and when i change something in my code my code will run and page refresh.. before it will only blank page.

Here is my code:

```
const handleGetOrderId = (e) => {
  return e.LabOrderId
}

<DataGrid
            pageSize={pageSize}
            onPageSizeChange={(newPageSize) => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
            rowsPerPageOptions={[10, 20, 50]}
            rowCount={
              data.Result.length === undefined ? 30 : data?.Result?.length
            }
            page={page}
            onPageChange={(newPage) => handlePage(newPage)}
            pagination
            rowGetter={(i) => data.Result[i]}
            paginationMode='server'
            className={classes.colCell}
            columns={[
              { headerName: 'ID Order Lab', field: 'LabOrderCode', width: 120 },
              { headerName: 'Nama Pasien', field: 'PatientName', width: 150 },
              {
                headerName: 'No Telp / Email',
                field: 'PhoneNumber',
                width: 150,
              },
              {
                headerName: 'Jenis Layanan',
                field: 'LabOrderType',
                width: 130,
              },
              {
                headerName: 'Booking time slot',
                field: 'BookingTimeSlot',
                width: 150,
                hideable: false,
              },
              {
                headerName: 'Tanggal Pemesanan',
                field: 'BookingDate',
                width: 180,
              },
              { headerName: 'Cabang', field: 'BranchName', width: 120 },
              {
                headerName: 'Harga',
                field: 'TotalTransaction',
                width: 100,
                renderCell: (params) => {
                  return (
                    <Typography variant='body3'>
                      {params.row.TotalTransaction === null
                        ? '-'
                        : `Rp ${parseInt(
                            params.row.TotalTransaction,
                          ).toLocaleString('id')}`}
                    </Typography>
                  )
                },
              },
              {
                headerName: 'Status Pembayaran',
                field: 'PaymentStatus',
                width: 180,
                renderCell: (params) => {
                  return <TrxBox data={params.row} />
                },
              },
              {
                headerName: 'Aksi',
                width: 100,
                renderCell: (params) => {
                  return (
                    <Typography
                      variant='body1'
                      color='primary'
                      onClick={() => handleClickOpen(params.row)}>
                      Detail Order
                    </Typography>
                  )
                },
              },
            ]}
            rows={data?.Result}
            getRowId={handleGetOrderId}
          />
```

Here my error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
```

is there anything i can improve from this piece of code? Thank you

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the code, I'd recommend to create a codesandbox that reproduce the issue. For a first step, try to change `data.Result.length` to `data?.Result.length`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.